# GestureDetector + ItemClick RecyclerView does not work together

Tags: java, android

I have looked for several times, but I think no one is facing the same issue that I'm facing right now. I have the following fragment:

**FRAGMENT XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/id"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="8dp"
android:paddingEnd="16dp"
android:paddingStart="16dp"
android:paddingTop="8dp"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true">


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**RecyclerView XML**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ll_id"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

**FRAGMENT JAVA CODE SNIPPET**

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View viewRoot = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_xml, container, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) viewRoot.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_id);

    recyclerView.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(getActivity()) {
        @Override
        public void onSwipeRight() {
            FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_left, R.anim.exit_to_right, R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_left);
            ft.replace(R.id.frameLayout, new Fragment2()).commit();
        }
    });
```

So, what I'm doing on the code above is adding a touch listener, so when the user swipe from right to left, the fragment goes to the other fragment (Fragment2)

This works perfectly fine! However... I need to add onClickListener inside my recyclerAdapter, so I can catch the click listener of each item. And here comes the problem... When adding a click listener, the swipe listener does not work. It seems that the listener of the click "overrides" my listener of the swipe. The question is. How to add both on the recyclerview, and make them work together?